# fontspec mathspec clash

Tags: fontspec, mathspec

I have just updated to `fontspec 2017/02/12 v2.6`. Now when I compile my code I get a clash with `mathspec`.

`C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex\mathspec\mathspec.sty:65: LaTeX Error: Option clash for package fontspec. [...Package[\eu@zf@math]{fontspec}[2008/08/09]]`

Example:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathspec}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Comment: How about... delete the line `\usepackage{fontspec}`.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer: `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}`

Comment: Or simply don't load fontspec as mathspec is doing it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Note that [currently top-voted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359706/201241) is not current for mathspec 0.2b (22 December 2016).

The [documentation](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/xetex/latex/mathspec/mathspec.pdf) states:

> It is not necessary to put `\usepackage{fontspec}` because `mathspec` will ensure that `fontspec` is loaded anyway. To load `fontspec` with some options, parse them through `mathspec`, for example,
>
> ```latex
> \usepackage[quiet]{mathspec}
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```latex
> \usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
> \usepackage{mathspec}
> ```

In practice, loading `fontspec` with any options gives me an error, but loading *just* mathspec works fine, and it accepts options which it passed on to fontspec.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I'm a bit confused by your remark "this answer is not current for 0.2b", do you mean your own answer (i.e., 'this answer') or the other answer by igm2013 (i.e., 'the other answer')? Maybe you can clarify this by editing your answer, initially I read it as "what I am now going to say does not apply to the current version of mathspec" which is probably not what you meant.

Comment: Great point @Marijn thank you. Revised accordingly.

Comment: `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}` from the other answer works for me perfectly.